# Generating a POCO from database, Detecting when to use List<object>

Tags: poco, t4

I am trying to write a T4 template to generate our poco models from the database. I have it generating everything perfectly accept the relationships. I have not gotten the ability to gather the foreignkey information but I am not sure how I can decide when to use a generic list or a property.

example:

```
public partial class Budget : IGeneratedModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SavingGoal SavingGoal { get; set; } <-- How do I know when to?
    public IEnumerable<SavingGoal> SavingGoals { get; set; }  <-- Or when to?
}

public partial class SavingGoal : IGeneratedModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BudgetId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

This is the model I have made to hold my relationship data. I can add more it is populated by a SQL query out of a few sys tables.

```
public class ForeignKeyInfo
{
    public string ForeignTable { get; set; }
    public string ForeignColumn { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryTable { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryColumn { get; set; }
    public string ConstraintName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: One way to distinguish between the two scenarios could be that if CurrentTable == fki.PrimaryTable then use a collection otherwise use a single instance. That is because a foreign key seems to refer to the primary key column ie it should be unique ==> single instance. Another idea is to enforce a naming Convention on the foreign keys which hints what scenario to pick.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I ended up dumping it and just going with PetaPoco instead. Found out they don't do what I was looking for either but in the end I guess it doesn't matter lol.